# Help with regex

Tags: regex

I got the following regex:

```
"throw new [a-zA-Z]+Exception"
```

I want do modify it so that all Argument exceptions (`"Argument[a-zA-Z]*Exception"`) are not included

How do I combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this page for more information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html

Keep in mind that different regex implementations may not support all of the options available, so YMMV.  If you have a regex designer tool that will let you test the expression live, I highly recommend it.  You need a negative lookahead expression:

```
"((?!Argument)[a-zA-Z])*Exception"
```

Make sure your regex library supports lookahead and negative lookahead expressions.

Comment: It didn't :( (Notepad++) But you answered the question with a proper example.

Comment: I used the regular expressions for this: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7588 ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need a *negative lookbehind*. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more details. Perl-specific but your particular implementation likely has something similar.

> Lookbehind has the same effect, but
>   works backwards. It tells the regex
>   engine to temporarily step backwards
>   in the string, to check if the text
>   inside the lookbehind can be matched
>   there. `(?<!a)b` matches a "b" that is
>   not preceded by an "a"

Comment: I tried `(?<!Argument[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]+Exception` and `(?<!(Argument[a-zA-Z]))[a-zA-Z]+Exception` but neither worked.

Comment: "Use lookbehind" is almost always bad advice.  Of those flavors that support lookbehinds, most place various kinds of restrictions on the kind of subexpressions you can use in them.  For example, `(<!Argument)Exception` is safe, but `(?<!Argument[A-Za-z]*)Exception` would only work in a very small minority of flavors.